# What should I do to Upload the React Native Expo App to App Store on Windows 10?

Tags: react-native, expo

I need to upload iOS App to App Store and I run the command "expo upload:ios" but it give the response
"Unsupported platform! This feature works on macOS only.". So, please help me out. How can I upload the App without having Mac Book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's impossible. you need MacOS and Xocde.
you can either rent a mac online, or run a virtual machine running MacOs. or maybe just buy a macbook or imac.
I know it sucks, and I had the same question before, but there is no other better options.